# Shell command does not work with Java execution

Tags: java

I'm using the following method to execute shell commands:

```
private String executeShellCommand(String command) {

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";           
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output.toString();

    }
```

This works fine for most commands except this one:

`executeShellCommand("brew install libimobiledevice");`

It works fine on the Mac terminal but not here.

I'm getting this error:

`Cannot run program "brew": error=2, No such file or directory`

Comment: brew is not on the path. Either add it to your path, or put the full path to brew such as /usr/bin/brew

Comment: Or if it really is something that only the *shell* would know about (e.g. a shell function) then you should launch the shell first, e.g. `/bin/bash ...`

Comment: I tried calling it from the full path but it returned the same error. How can I launch the shell and then run commands @JonSkeet? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can install brew by the following：

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: How do you know that `brew` is *not* installed? Maybe the `PATH` is not configured to include `brew`?

Comment: Brew is already installed. I'm guessing the command is not recognized for some reason.